# How to set a QML plugin as the source for a Loader

Tags: qt, qml

I've created a QML plugin and I can use it as :

```
import "MyElement" 1.0

Rectangle{
    width:500;height:500;
    MyElem{

    }
}
```

`MyElem` is the plugin.
Now I'm wondering how I can use this plugin as a **source** for a **Loader** element? The source of loader expects a string but here we have a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it for the loader like this:

```
import "MyElement" 1.0

Component {
  id: myElement
  MyElem{
  }
}
Loader { sourceComponent: myElement}
```